# How do I run a command at a certain time of day (IRL)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-spigot

I need to find a plugin or rig up some command blocks that will run console commands at specific times a day.  The most basic need is for the /restart command, but I also have world edit commands I want to run on some schedules too.

I have a spigot server on 1.15.2, command blocks, placeholderAPI with the localtime extension, and the ability to install other plugins of course.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I have my server running inside a screen session.
I can then use cron (or anything else, for that matter) to send commands to that screen session.

As an example, here's how i broadcast that i'm about to shut down the server. Adjust the command to your taste

```
/usr/bin/screen -p 0 -S ftb -X eval 'stuff "say SERVER SHUTTING DOWN. Saving map..."\\015'
```

- -p lets you select which window to attach to.
- -S lets you select a named session to attach to.
- -X is the command you want to send

look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen) for more info on the screen command if you need it

Hopefully that'll let you do what you need.

edit:foolishly, i assumed you were using linux...simply because i am.

Comment: That's a really cool solution!  I'm not using linux unfortunately, but I applaud the creativity.